# Issues with the game

Tags: discussion, stackegg

Why can't people see that the egg game is just a cycle:

```
ask
answer
upvote
downvote (do not close)
```

once successful, a cycle adds a star to the right sections, gradually filling them each cycle. Each star lasts for 4 votes. Go figure :)

(and once every 10 cycles, close)

Proof by counter example(acceptable?): current game has idiots who cannot count.

Comment: Is that the *optimal* strategy, though? How many days does it take to win?

Comment: @balpha I'd say 5 cycles to fill the stars, and continuations to keep it full.

Comment: "I'd say" doesn't particularly sound like you have a lot of empirical evidence :)

Comment: @balpha give me a method to get empirical evidence and I'll give it to you :)

Comment: A strange game. The only losing move is not to play.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a rant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the goal is to win the Internet, you just lost your shirt.

When an April fool's easter egg game becomes cause to rant on meta and call other players of said easter egg game "idiots", I'm pretty sure you're taking it too seriously and, as far as I can see, that's the only sure way to loose. Because then the joke is on you.

Lighten up. Click some buttons.

Comment: Clicked. The `upvote` and the `accept`.